# Now that Evernote free is limited to two devices, what should I switch to?

Tags: note-taking

I'm using at least three devices, a windows 10 desktop, a macbook pro and my android phone, which means that Evernote free is no longer an option, and since I don't really like it, I don't want to start paying for it.

I basically want to export all of my Evernote data to some other service and never look back.

I need text notes across all my devices and an easy way to export/import my evernote data into the new service. I have images and audio in my Evernote, but I don't need any of them. I haven't touched them in years.

I use Evernote as a place to write down any ideas I have, on whatever device I'm on. Edit history is not important, and neither is formatting or markdown support.

Simplenote seems like the easy answer, but they don't seem to support folders. I could use tags instead, but have yet to find a sync tool that translates folders into tags for me. Arguably tags are more flexible.

Comment: Is self-hosting an option? Then [OpenNote](http://freedif.org/simple-opensource-alternative-to-onenote-and-evernote-opennote/) might be an option (though [its Github presence](https://github.com/FoxUSA/OpenNote) looks like maintenance stopped). Another comparable self-hosted candidate would be [Paperwork](http://paperwork.rocks/), which is [still active](https://github.com/twostairs/paperwork) (Android app [here](https://github.com/theSoenke/Paperwork-Android)). I haven't tried either, so I can just leave a comment.

Comment: I have never tried it, but I know some people are happy with open-source Turtl: https://turtl.it/

Answer (score 7):

There is [Google Keep](https://www.google.com/keep/).

This takes simple text notes which it arranges as a number of cards, which can be treated as folders.
It supports voice notes and photos.

Like Evernote, it has apps for Android, iOS, etc. or can be accessed from the [web](http://keep.google.com/).

I simply copied and pasted my notes from Evernote to Keep.  That was sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are on Apple ecosystem, you can use the native notes application. It syncs well across mobile & desktop. The latest version can also import from evernote.
2. As Chenmunka mentioned, you can use [Google Keep](https://www.google.com/keep/)
3. You can also use [Microsoft Onenote](https://www.onenote.com/). It is available on desktop & mobile. Troyhunt covers how to [migrate](https://www.troyhunt.com/evernote-2/) from evernote to onenote.
4. There are many other apps coming up. One such app is [notion](https://www.notion.so/), which support wiki, todo list, and note taking.

Answer (score 2):

[GNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gnotes&hl=en) was a very good replacement IMO. It supports PC via browser and Android, I'm not sure about IOS. It has the same features as many note taking apps, only with a small name. There are currently some syncing issues with GNotes, and I'm hoping it is all resolved soon. If you'd like some quick syncs between different devices, I'd suggest giving GNotes a go.

There are other bigger names in note taking apps like the others mentioned. then there are the unsung heroes like GNotes, Somnotes, Journey (I'd suggest giving it a go too) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a newish kid on the block.  [Notion](https://notion.so/) has all the features I need.
It has apps for Apple, Android and Windows, and, of course, is available via a browser.  At the moment the Android app is rather buggy but access from a browser on an Android device is fine.

Notion allows pages and subpages within notes.
A great plus is the ability to embed a [database](https://www.notion.so/help/intro-to-databases) which makes it an alternative to [Airtable](https://www.airtable.com/).
It has an [API](https://developers.notion.com/) to allow integrations.

Notion is free for personal use and has various paid levels.  Even the free level enables you to publish content on a webpage, so you can share with others up to a point.